# Re-programming injection pump on French Ford Focus TDCi

Tags: ford, diesel, focus, fuel-injection, tdci

I replaced the engine on my 2003 Ford Focus (**French** TDCi) and I plugged it to clear the error codes.

Now it starts ok but stops after 10 minutes.

I read that when a new injection pump is installed, you actually have 600 seconds to re-program it, or the car stops.

I have no idea what the procedure is.

Is there a specific code to find on the pump? If so, where is it?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the instructions I found from [this document](http://www.autodiagnos.com/sites/default/files/ford_injector_programming_tdci_ad.pdf). It looks as though you have to program the pump and injectors into the PCU using some type interfacing tool. I would bet this is probably only available through the dealer, though I could be wrong. Check with a local shop, but would bet this is not something you can do at home. The document has several pictures as to where to find the codes for both the pump and the injectors.

> Injector Programming (TDCi Engines)
>   This function is required by service centres when an Injector needs to be replaced, or
>   there is a driveability problem.
>   For 1.8 TDCi and 2.0 TDCi engines the each injector has a 16-digit calibration code
>   stamped on the body.
>   For 1.6 TDCi engines the each injector has an 8-digit calibration code stamped on the
>   body.
>   These codes relate to the electrical and structural characteristics of each injector,
>   which are defined during production. The PCM must know the calibration codes for
>   each injector in order to treat and operate the injectors in the correct manner. This
>   helps to reduce emissions and improve performance. The code must be programmed
>   in by communicating and downloading the code into the PCMs memory.
>   There are three common situations which demand this function.
>   1. After Injector replacement.
>   2. Fuel injection system ‘calibration’.
>   3. To cure drivability problems. Lack of power, black smoke and the presence of
>   DTC’s P2336, P2337, P2338 can often be fixed by re-entering the existing 4
>   injector codes.
>
> NOTE:
>   • On earlier model years (approx pre-2003) it is not possible to read the actual
>   injector codes. On these vehicles you will see ’00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00’ or ‘FF FF
>   FF FF FF FF FF FF’ or a mixture.
>   • After entering an injector code the fuel system will initially run without any pilot
>   injection sequence. The car must be driven for a few miles to correct this.
>   The codes of the ORIGINAL injectors fitted to vehicle can be found on a label, which
>   is fitted to the side of the engine or on the engine rocker top (if it has not yet been
>   removed).
>
> The codes on the label are in the following format:

- (1&2) X1111111122222222X
- (3&4) X3333333344444444X

> Where:
>   11111111 is the code for injector 1,
>   22222222 is the code for injector 2,
>   33333333 is the code for injector 3,
>   44444444 is the code for injector 4.
>   NOTE: The injectors are in the physical order, NOT firing order.
>
> Injector Programming (TDCi Engines)
>   This function is required by service centres when an Injector needs to be replaced, or
>   there is a driveability problem.
>   For 1.8 TDCi and 2.0 TDCi engines the each injector has a 16-digit calibration code
>   stamped on the body.
>   For 1.6 TDCi engines the each injector has an 8-digit calibration code stamped on the
>   body.
>   These codes relate to the electrical and structural characteristics of each injector,
>   which are defined during production. The PCM must know the calibration codes for
>   each injector in order to treat and operate the injectors in the correct manner. This
>   helps to reduce emissions and improve performance. The code must be programmed
>   in by communicating and downloading the code into the PCMs memory.
>   There are three common situations which demand this function.
>   1. After Injector replacement.
>   2. Fuel injection system ‘calibration’.
>   3. To cure drivability problems. Lack of power, black smoke and the presence of
>   DTC’s P2336, P2337, P2338 can often be fixed by re-entering the existing 4
>   injector codes.
>
> NOTE: The injectors on the label are in firing order, NOT physical order. The top left
>   code is Injector 1 (Cyl.1), the top right code is Injector 2 (Cyl.3), the bottom left is
>   Injector 3 (Cyl.4) and the bottom right is Injector 4 (Cyl.2). Where Injector is the firing
>   number, Cylinder is the physical number.
>   When replacing an Injector the code stamped on the body of the new Injector must
>   be programmed into the PCM, NOT the code on the label.
>   WARNING: Before attempting Injector Programming it is necessary for the
>   vehicle to be left stationary with the Engine off for at least 8 hours. This is to
>   ensure that the engine is stone cold before Injector Programming is performed.
>   Failure to follow these instructions may result in failure of the Injector
>   Programming function and/or drivability problems.

**EDIT:** I found on [this site](http://www.talkford.com/topic/149745-fuel-pump-question/) which says:

> The TDCI pump doesn't need coded as it is mechanical. I had mines changed a month ago and it wasn't coded in to the car.

and

> Nope no code for pump on TDCI only injectors

So, I'm thinking this is not your problem. It could be that the "600 second time limit" is for re-coding the injectors into the system after the pump replacement, but not sure. Also, check the PCM for codes, as there are several mentioned above which will go away when the injectors are recoded.

Comment: You can [find it here](http://uk.picclick.com/Ford-F-SUPER-2-Interface-Scanner-USB-SCAN-221263082834.html) for 18 GPB.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the input (Can't yet, not enough rep coz of the bounty)! I'm not trying to program the injectors but the pump itself though.
I'll borrow an "ids" scanner device. I'm not sure what make/model it will be but I know I'm still looking for the pump's code and instructions on how to "put it in" ;-)

Comment: The pictures in there also show where the code for the pump is located. I would venture to assume it's going to be along the same lines as programming the injectors, just a different selection. For some reason I thought the injector instructions where in there as well because it had these pictures.

Comment: @ArmelLarcier ... please see the EDIT.

Comment: @Paulster2 Thanks! This is helping. Indeed it seems I have to program the injectors themselves. The pictures are helping!